# Data dependency in classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, forms, class

I've prepared a picture for my question which is shown below.
[image]

Now I will tell you what I want. As you can see I have three forms.

- Form1 gets some data (like int, string, structure, array - it doesn't matter) from a class
- Form1 opens Form2
- Form2 opens Form3

And now I want to have an access from Form3 to data from Form1. And here is my question: how to create objects of these forms. I have a problem to get a correct data dependence between them. 
I don't have a code because I only create a new form instance like this `Dim f2 As Form2 = New Form2()` and then from Form2: `Dim f3 As Form3 = New Form3()`
And then in Form3 I do this: `Dim f1 As Form1 = New Form1()` and I don't have access to data in Form1.

Comment: The class could be in charge of all this.  Rather than a form "getting data from" a class, the class can create the form, show it and push the required data to the form.  When form2 is required, it too is created, shown and managed by the class....etc   Forms are best as user input sandboxes not program control elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the constructor for your `Form2` and `Form3` to take arguments - specifically you could make an array containing the data from `Form1` and then pass that array through into `Form2` and `Form3`.

This is done by making a `Public Sub New` method in the code behind `Form2` and `Form3` whose signature contains the datatypes you want to pass across.

You'll want to assign the passed over data to a private variable in the constructor, so you can then reference it with other methods on the new form.

Comment: Just to add. You would probably want to declare private variable(s) at the class level within Form2 and Form3, and then set them using value(s) passed into the overridden constructors. This would then make them available to other methods in Form2 and Form3.

Comment: @ChrisG Very true. I've used this approach before in form design. I'll edit it in.

Comment: And what do you think about that? In `Form1`: `Dim f2 As Form2` and in constructor: `f2 = New Form2(Me)`. Next in `Form2`: `Dim f1 As Form1` and in constructor (which takes argument of type Form1 called form): `f1 = form`. And in `Form3`: `Dim f2 As Form2` and in constructor (also takes argument of type Form2 called form): `f2 = form`. Then I can have an access by using this in `Form3`: `f2.f1.data`. What about this, is it correct?